# Create an array in which every element is filled by a struct (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have to create a tic tac toe game. I had created a bidimensional array for the game board in which elements went from 1 to 9 and during the game they could be changed by 'X' or "O'. However, my instructions tell me I must do an array that is filled with a struct in every element. I wanted to know how can I achieve this. EDIT: how to achieve putting each struct inside the array, which is the part I can't quite understand.

This are the instructions of my professor: "To create this game, you must use an array where each element is an element of the game board and in each element there should be an struct that has the attributes "mark" and "symbol" to verify if the element is empty and, if it's not, which was the piece that was placed or will be placed"

I had previously done one struct with nine atributes like this:

```
   struct Sitio {
      char a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3;
   };

   struct Sitio valor = {0};

   void Valores() {
       valor.a1 = '1';
       valor.a2 = '2';
       valor.a3 = '3';
       valor.b1 = '4';
       valor.b2 = '5';
       valor.b3 = '6';
       valor.c1 = '7';
       valor.c2 = '8';
       valor.c3 = '9';
   }

   char *num[3][3] = {
      {&valor.a1, &valor.a2, &valor.a3},
      {&valor.b1, &valor.b2, &valor.b3},
     {&valor.c1, &valor.c2, &valor.c3}
   };
```

Which worked without errors, but my instructions tell me I should do a struct for each, and each struct with two attributes as I previously mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, your struct should have attribute "mark", which will say if this element is empty or not, and another attribute "symbol", which will contain the symbol if there's any.

Here is how it should be:

```
struct element {
    int mark;
    char symbol;
};
```

where `mark` could be 0 (if the element is empty) and 1 (if it contains symbol).
You can declare an array of structs as follows:

```
struct element arr[9];
```

I can't help you to write the project, because this is your assignment and this will be very specific to your case and won't offer another help for anyone else.
I require you to read more about structs in C.